# Iterated Graphing in For Loop via Python

Tags: python

```
for k in range(10):
        rtpi = (pratio / float(math.pi)) + x*0
        plt.plot(x,rtpi,'r')
```

This produces a flat line. How can I do this:

```
for k in range(10):
        rtpi = (pratio / float(math.pi)) + x*0
        plt.scatter(x,rtpi,'r')
```

Basically, for every individual point, I would like one point to be represented on the graph per 1 point on the x-axis.

Comment: "`... + x*0`"  - not sure I see much of a purpose for that. Also, since `rtpi` doesn't seem to depend on `k` at all, there's not really a point in recalculating it every iteration...

Comment: If x is not somewhere in there, it throws an x and y must be the same dimension error. This was the only way I could get it to compile and not interfere. I want the ratio to pi (rtpi) to be calculated 10 times and plotted 10 times. Scatter plot. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/spines_demo_bounds.html) suggests you should use plt.plot and add an "o"

```
for k in range(10):
    rtpi = (pratio / float(math.pi)) + x*0
    plt.plot(x,rtpi,'ro')
```

Comment: plt.scatter  has the following error. Not implemented for this type.

Comment: Ah yes. Should be plt.plot from the example. I will edit the original.